# triangulation of a surface, adapted to curvature

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d, triangulation

This is about my [printed models of mathematical objects](http://www.shapeways.com/shops/bendwavy).

All of the designs that I've published so far consist of grids of bent ‘rods’, and in most of them the spacing of vertices depends on the rod's local curvature; that's easy enough. But I think some of these figures would look better as continuous surfaces, and it's not obvious to me how to arrange the vertices efficiently — that is, to triangulate the surface just finely enough that it's accurate to within the printer's resolution.

So: given a surface defined by well-behaved functions $x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v)$, is there a standard way to choose vertices in $u,v$ space so that each edge length is roughly proportional to the radius of curvature in that direction?

Comment: Googling "curvature dependent triangulation" will give you many leads on this topic.

Comment: Mostly I find copies or citations of Karkanis & Stewart on approximating *implicit* surfaces (i.e., surfaces where $f(x,y,z)$ is constant) with *nearly equilateral* triangles …

Comment: The article "Best data dependent triangulation" (the 3rd one from the google result) is not about implicit surfaces. You can also download the pdf file from the website.